# Using Next() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="comment_text">
        <a>Blah blah</a> THIS IS WHAT I NEED
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the text `THIS IS WHAT I NEED` from the above div, this is what I do usually:

```
var val = $.trim($('#container').find('.comment_text').text());
```

but this also gets the `a` tag, so how I should get only the text? I'm thinking of next() but it's not working:

```
 var val = $.trim($('#container').find('.comment_text a').next().text());
```

Thanks

Comment: something like: `var val = $.trim($('#container').find('.comment_text a').text());` should work

Comment: @user123_456 but it's not!

Comment: even with `.comment_text a`? notice this `a` tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting unwrapped textnodes with jQuery is a bit more involved :

```
$('#container .comment_text').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GrDBz/)

You should propably trim that as well.

You could also do:

```
$('#container .comment_text a').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GrDBz/1/)

Comment: It's not, did you open your console ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#container').clone().find('a').remove().end().text();
```

You can remove the anchor temporarily to get the remaining text,  and by cloning it you don't interrupt the DOM  elements.

Comment: @adeneo sorry, i forgot .clone() `var txt = $('#container').clone().find('a').remove().end().text();`  http://jsfiddle.net/GrDBz/4/

Comment: Now it would work, but why it's a community wiki is still beyond me ?

Comment: Sorry, did it quickly on my phone while I was out the door. Thanks to the Community for the edit; Yes, needs to be found first, then removed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone the div and remove the anchor then you'll get the text :

```
var clone = $('.comment_text').clone();
clone.find('a').remove();

var val = $.trim(clone.text());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can  try the following:

```
var val = $.trim($('.comment_text').find("a").html();
```